# How to GET data from s3 using postman

Tags: amazon-s3, postman

I am trying to get data from file in s3 bucket. In postman set the response to GET for https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test-bucket-name/file-name? Entered Access Key: xxx123 Secret Access: xxxx12322 aws region: eu-west-1 service name: s3

In response i am getting access denied. Do i need to do any pre work to get the access keys working as they are generated for users and are used for CLI commands from my machine.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to make sure that you have an IAM user with the **AmazonS3ReadOnlyPolicy** to gain access to the object present in it.

I had this similar problem when I first started AWS and this link helped me :-

> http://raaviblog.com/how-to-get-aws-s3-bucket-object-data-using-postman/#google_vignette

Have a look, cheers.

Comment: I followed above site and i am getting Access Denied message in postman. I have admin permissions on the bucket.

Comment: I have generated session key and entered in authorization and that didn't work as well. I get could not get any response message when i enter session

Comment: In which region have you created your bucket ?

Comment: If it is eu-west-1 then try replacing your endpoint with this s3-accesspoint.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Check if you have given public access to your bucket. If at all you have blocked it then you cannot send any requests from the internet to the bucket due to which you are seeing access denied.

Comment: Public access is set up to bucket. I have just realized i have multiple roles set up for my user account. Keys which i have provided in postman are generated against my IAM user profile, but not for the profile which i am trying to use. Not sure how i can bypass the profile

Comment: Then update either your bucket policy with the current IAM user or update your IAM policy by adding the bucket to the user you are using. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get list of files in the bucket. Issue was with permissions on the file.

Answer (score 0):

I also followed the [blog post](http://raaviblog.com/how-to-get-aws-s3-bucket-object-data-using-postman/#google_vignette) mentioned above and added an individual `Bucket Policy`.

[image: AWS Management Console]

I didn't want to use the generic `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policy but specify one just for the particular bucket. I also wanted to make sure that you can only use the `GetObject` action and therefore have to know what the file you request is called.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Grant_GetObject_To_YourUserNameHere",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ConfigureS3BucketObjectRetriever",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/S3BucketObjectRetriever"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```